# Does rebuilding state stores in Kafka Streams propagate duplicate records to downstream topics?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, restore, stateful

I'm currently using Kafka Streams for a stateful application. The state is **not** stored in a Kafka state store though, but rather just in memory for the moment being. This means whenever I restart the application, all state is lost and it has to be rebuilt by processing all records from the start.

After doing some research on Kafka state stores, this seems to be exactly the solution I'm looking for to persist state between application restarts (either in memory or on disk). However, I find the resources online lack some pretty important details, so I still have a couple of questions on how this would work exactly:

- If the stream is set to start from offset `latest`, will the state still be (re)calculated from all the previous records?
- If previously already processed records need to be reprocessed in order to rebuild the state, will this propagate records through the rest of the Streams topology (e.g. InputTopic -> stateful processor -> OutputTopic, will this result in duplicated records in the OutputTopic because of rebuilding state)?

Comment: Are you referring to KTables?

Comment: @cricket_007 no, rather an `persistentKeyValueStore` which I think is different? You are supposed to be able to do something like `builder.addStateStore(storeBuilder)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

State stores use their own `changelog` topics, and kafka-streams state stores take on responsibility for loading from them.  If your state stores are uninitialised, your kafka-streams app will rehydrate its local state store from the changelog topic using `EARLIEST`, since it has to read every record.

This means the startup sequence for a brand new instance is roughly:

- Observe there is no local state-store cache
- Load the local state store by consumeing from the changelog topic for the statestore (the state-store's topic name is `<state-store-name>-changelog`)
- Read each record and update a local rocksDB instance accordingly
- Do not emit anything, since this is an application-service, not your actual topology
- Read your consumer-groups offsets using `EARLIEST` or `LATEST` according to how you configured the topology.  Not this is only a concern if your consumer group doesn't have any offsets yet
- Process stuff, emitting records according to the topology

Whether you set your actual topology's `auto.offset.reset` to `LATEST` or `EARLIEST` is up to you.  In the event they are lost, or you create a new group, its a balance between potentially skipping records (`LATEST`) vs handling reprocessing of old records & deduplication (`EARLIEST`),

Long story short: state-restoration is different from processing, and handled by kafka-streams its self.

Comment: The point about `auto.offset.reset` is not correct -- `auto.offset.reset` only applies if there is no committed offsets. If committed offset are found processing starts from there. -- Ie, `auto.offset.reset` is usually only relevant on the first startup of the application, for which case there no state to be recovered as it will be empty on initial startup.

Comment: Hmm.  my point wasn't very clear - I was trying to make the reader think about what happens in the case that offsets are lost, since the setting was raised, but I'll polish it

Answer (score 2):

> If the stream is set to start from offset `latest`, will the state still be (re)calculated from all the previous records?

If you are re-launching *the same application* (e.g. after having stopped it before), then state *will not* be recalculated by reprocessing the original input data.  Instead, the state will be restored from its "backup" (every state store or KTable is durably stored in a Kafka topic, the so-called "changelog topic" of that table/state store for such purposes) so that its data is exactly what it was when the application was stopped.  This behavior enables you to seamlessly stop+restart your applications without skipping over records that arrived between "stop" and "restart".

But there is a different caveat that you need to be aware of:  The configuration to set the offset start point (`latest` or `earliest`) is only used when you run your Kafka Streams application *for the first time*. Afterwards, whenever you stop+restart your application, it will always continue where it previously stopped.  That's because, if the app has run at least once, it has stored its consumer offset information in Kafka, which allows it to know from where to automatically resume operations once it is being restarted.

If you need the different behavior of always (re)starting from e.g. the `latest` offsets (thus potentially skipping records that arrived in between when you stopped the application and when you restarted it), you must [reset your Kafka Streams application](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/app-reset-tool.html).  One of the steps the reset tool performs is removing the application's consumer offset information from Kafka, which makes the application think that it was never started before, so to speak.

> If previously already processed records need to be reprocessed in order to rebuild the state, will this propagate records through the rest of the Streams topology (e.g. InputTopic -> stateful processor -> OutputTopic, will this result in duplicated records in the OutputTopic because of rebuilding state)?

This reprocessing will not happen by default as explained above.  State will be automatically reconstructed to its prior state (pun intended) at the point when the application was stopped.

Reprocessing would only happen if you manually reset your application (see above) and e.g. configure the application to re-read historical data (like setting `auto.offset.reset` to `earliest` after you did the reset).